# Are there WMS servers providing maps of UTM zones, actually in the zone projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, wms, utm, services

There are lots of EPSG:4326 (lat lon) services out there but if one has to use an `UTM projected map` as base layer to display utm scenes, are there any WMS endpoints `publicly` available for that?

Answer (score 1):

when you googling you can see some of utm supported wms service... for example Toporama Web Map Service has lots of projections available for service requests.

When you write [this](http://wms.ess-ws.nrcan.gc.ca/wms/toporama_en?VERSION=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities&service=wms) to browser, you will see lots of projection as defined NAD83 / UTM zone in Layer section.

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is not specific with regard to an area of interest, I did a quick web search for "wms utm" and came up with 2 almost immediately.  They are both based in Canada, and are government data portals.

1. [The Atlas of Canada](http://atlas.nrcan.gc.ca/auth/english/dataservices/web_map_service.html):  This provides a number of data layers on a world, continental and national level.  The wms layers are available in quite a number of different projections, including but not limited to the UTM zones.
2. [GeoBase Canada](http://www.geobase.ca/geobase/en/wms/index.html):  This organization is a consortium of mapping agencies in Canada.

This was a quick search.  I am sure a more detailed search including your area of interest, would provide more relevant results.

Answer (score 1):

The Norwegian Mapping Authority has several free "to use for non-commercial purposes" WMS services for Norway (and, some less detailed of Europe), in UTM Zones 31-35N.

Available here: http://www.statkart.no/?module=Articles;action=Article.publicShow;ID=14089/

But, you should be a bit more specific as to *where* your area of interest is?

Comment: I was not specific because I am looking for global coverage. I guess it would be attainable only putting together several servers